# Are there any data modeling exercises for Cassandra like Retwis for Redis?

Tags: database, data-modeling, nosql, cassandra

I'm trying to learn how to map the entities/actors/objects/things in my application for storage in Cassandra.  There was a great tutorial for Redis on modeling Twitter data and typical access patterns called Retwis [1].  I've found a couple of examples for Cassandra.

*How did you start to gain an intuition for Cassandra's data model?*

[1] http://retwis.antirez.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://github.com/ericflo/twissandra is a twitter clone in the same vein as retwis, originally for 0.3 and now being updated for 0.6.  Catch erifclo in #cassandra on irc if you have questions.

Comment: Nice. Do you know of any other similar exercises? I am not finding (m)any.

Answer (score 2):

- you should start with [WTF is a SuperColumn](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model) to understand the data model.
- [up and running with cassandra](http://blog.evanweaver.com/articles/2009/07/06/up-and-running-with-cassandra/) is also a very good starting tutorial and it has
  example schemas for a blog and for twitter.